# How to export/import DB dump in oracle using SQL Developer?

Tags: oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a schema 'A'. I want to import this in schema 'B'. I am using SQL Developer for this. I try to use tools->DBA but got privilege error. Can we have any exp/imp command which we can use. Please help.

Comment: install an oracle client, use the expdp CLI, docs are here https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sutil/oracle-data-pump-export-utility.html#GUID-D5455260-C28C-475F-9E0E-2BE227E7F0E3 .. or ask your dba to grant you access to the DBA views and exec privs on data pump plsql apis and you can use sql developer

Comment: expdp username/password directory=my_dir dumpfile=tables_exp.dmp full=yes

Comment: I have execute above query on sql developer but got unknown command error

Comment: expdp is a program included with your oracle database in $ORACLE_HOME, not with sql developer

Comment: I have access to DBA user. Can i export the from user A to user B from DBA user using SQL developer utility

Comment: yes you can do that

Comment: ORA-39002: invalid operation
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SYS_ERROR", line 79
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_DATAPUMP", line 3507
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_DATAPUMP", line 3756
ORA-06512: at line 12

Comment: I am getting this error while using data pump from sql developer. plz help

Comment: more info, show us what you're doing - at the end of your db pump wizard we generate and show you the pl/sql block we're generating - you need to share that. also, what version of sqldev and what version of oracle are you using

Comment: I am using oracle 11g and for sqldev we are using version 17.4.